# How to prevent slurm from terminating entire job when last process fails or is killed?

Tags: slurm

I am launching 4 process via job script. These 4 processes launch successfully on the slurm host. But if the last process(4th one) crashed or get killed, the whole job get terminated. That's not the case with first 3 process. If I kill any one of first 3 process, the job stays there until all remaining processes complete their execution. But if I killed the last one, it terminates and kill first three processes as well.

my job_scrpt.sh contains:
python process1 & process2 & process3 & process4

how does the job termination(in both successful and failed cases) works in slurm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
process1 &
process2 &
process3 &
process4
```

the script will terminate as soon as `process4` terminates (it is the only one "blocking"); and so will the job.

You should write

```
process1 &
process2 &
process3 &
process4 &
wait
```

so as to send all four processes to the background, and the `wait` command will block the script until all of them terminate, and so will the job.